# Cosmos not showing up for me

Tags: c#, builder, cosmos

I've been searching for a few hours for a solution for my problems. But I've downloaded Cosmos (operating system) using visual studio 2015 community edition. At first I downloaded the userkit, then realized that I wanted the devkit (maybe). All the examples I see online are using this:

```
using Cosmos.Compiler.Builder;
```

But that isn't working for me. ( I did change the properties to use the 3.5 framework, i read that I must use that and now it's not finding Cosmos anywhere. Before when I was using framework 4.5 I could use cosmos, but only Cosmos.System and one other. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

This is what I'm getting in Kernel.cs when I first start a cosmos project:

```
using System;
using System.Colletions.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Sys = Cosmos.System;

namespace CosmosKernel1
{
    public class Kernel : Sys.Kernel
    {
        protected override void BeforeRun()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cosmos booted successfully. Type a line of text to get it echoed back.");
        }

        protected override void Run()
        {
            Console.Write("Input: ");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Text type: ");
            Console.WriteLine(input);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that you have a COSMOS PROJECT and not a typical c# console app or something.

Second, after confirming that, make sure you have cosmos.compiler and all the cosmos dlls in your references.

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKW3BrclAUY

Comment: I did create the cosmos project lol. But I'll check the dlls right now. I didn't think about that.

Comment: @Vince anything yet?

Comment: I'm so confused on this. I edited my post to show what code I get when I first startup the project. But most examples online show this http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-an-Operating-System-in-C/?ALLSTEPS I'm not sure why I'm getting a different output.

Comment: @Vince I wouldnt use that tutorial. It's incredibly outdated. Did you import the DLLS in References yet? if it would be useful to you, i'll add a mini tutorial in the answer showing how to import the DLLS.

Comment: Mini tutorial would be nice. Is there any updated tutorials on the net that you're aware of? As they all seem to say the same as the link i provided.

Comment: @Vince Heres a tutorial that I used to use and it fits the format of your project (with beforerun and run) perfectly. no xboot, which is very outdated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130984/discussion-between-xena-os-development-team-and-vince).